# Laravel 5.3 HTTPS Routes

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I've read everywhere that Laravel can detect when the user is browsing via HTTPS and uses that to generate routes accordingly, but this appears to be untrue.

I've used a configuration in the `AppServiceProvider` to force all generated URLs to be prefixed for HTTPS but this only masks an underlying problem.

I have Laravel sitting on an EC2 instance. There is no load balancer and I haven't configured a proxy. This is purely a development instance.

How can I get URLs generated by the `route` helper to use HTTPS?

Comment: As far as I know, the generated URLs should be relative, not absolute, so there wouldn't be a protocol on it.

Comment: They're being generated as absolute URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is on HTTPS page, Laravel's `route()` helper will generate HTTPS URL. Since Google Chrome is already marks HTTP websites as insecure, it is a good idea is to rewrite all HTTP requests to HTTPS. There are many ways to do that, but as far as I know the best is to setup your web server to do the job.

Sample VH for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost my.app:80>
   ServerName my.app
   Redirect permanent / https://my.app
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my.app:443>
    DocumentRoot /home/my/public
    ServerName my.app
    ServerAlias my.app
    ServerAlias *.my.app
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key

    <Directory /home/my/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `If you're on HTTPS page, Laravel's route() helper will generate HTTPS url.` That's the problem - it doesn't, at all. And my virtual host is already configured to support HTTPS.

Comment: It seems something's wrong with web server config file. The config above is from a pretty big project and it works perfectly, please try it. It rewrites all HTTP requests to HTTPS, so you'll never be able to load HTTP page.

Comment: It looks like I hadn't turned on the SSLEngine. Routes seem to be fine now.